# Sharepoint 2010 Server down after installing updates?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I just installed the following on my Sharepoint 2010 Dev environment and now I am unable to browse to any of the sites neither am I able to create  a web application.
Is there a way I can roll back to previous settings or uninstall the updates?
The products and configuration wizard failed as well.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0F56EBFB-183F-4F4D-9D41-DF1E5ACEB893  (Service Pack 1 for MSF)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B9FCDC42-EEA4-4C08-9169-A9A73E55B8D4  (Service Pack 1 for SP 2010)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597058  (December 2011 CU for MSF)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597014  (December 2011 CU for SP 2010)

[image]

Comment: What error did the Config Wizard fail with?  That is where you'll need to troubleshoot.

Comment: Trevor's right, the error from the config wizard will help figure out the problem. Updates cannot be uninstalled either, which means your only rollback options are restoring a snapshot (if this is a VM) or rebuilding the farm and restoring from backups.

Comment: Also, try re-running psconfig again.  I had to do it twice on my dev environment.  The second time was successful.

Comment: Try rebooting the machine and re-run the psConfig as Sween suggests.

Comment: @sween_sp I tried rebooting and rerunning twice with no luck.

Comment: I have updated my Question to with a screenshot of the error. Thanks

Comment: If I were to uninstall Sharepoint, would it get rid of the updates as well. I could then reinstall sharepoint and restore from backup.

Comment: While the screenshot contains the exception, you still need to review the actual log file for context.

Comment: A side note on the updates:  You DO NOT need to install SharePoint Foundation updates on SharePoint Server.  The updates to SharePoint Server include the Foundation updates (e.g. you only need to apply the SP1 package for Server, you do not need to apply the Foundation SP1 package).

Comment: @John Chapman That was my first thought as well, until we opened a ticket with microsoft to resolve one of our issues and they suggested we install 4 of those updates.

Comment: One more thing to try, if you haven't already,  is to run psconfig from a command line instead of the GUI.  Go to a SharePoint Management Shell window and type psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait

Comment: @sween_sp I ended up reinstalling shrepoint (after much troubleshooting) and restoring my site collections (luckily there were just a few.) But thanks for the tip. I can try it if it happens again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried everything suggested on this post and a lot more odd options with no luck. 
I just took down my dev server and brought it back up and restored my site collection back up.

Of course, I did not have much data (in which case it would not be recommended at all) but atleast it fixed my problem.